# Laravel model existed but return Class 'App\Entities\OrignalTripModel' not found

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5

Model included in my Controller as

```
use App\Entities\OrignalTripModel;
```

But it returns

```
Class 'App\Entities\OrignalTripModel' not found
```

i am using it into controller as

```
OrignalTripModel::create($inputs);
```

Comment: 1) Did you dump autoload? `composer dump-autoload`; 2) Does your file path match it's namespace? In your case the file `OrignalTripModel` should be in `namespace App\Entities;` and it's path should be `app/Entities/OrignalTripModel.php`. 3) Check your spelling. Shouldn't it be `OriginalTripModel`?

Comment: 2) is working . actaully my namespace is wrong in this model. thanks 
 a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly include it in your controller like this:
use `App\Entities\OrignalTripModel;`

And please check namespace for the model OriginalTripModel to see if it has `namespace App\Entities;` and that is extends model like this `class OriginalTripModel extends Model`

Comment: I have moved all Models into Entities folder. all models are aceessing except this one

Comment: ok, have you checked the naming of OriginalTripModel that it corresponds to the class name and file name.

Comment: I stated that in my answer, so if it this was helpful, kindly mark as answered as reference for other users